# Change DIV display value using Javascript/Jquery function

Tags: javascript, html, function

Update: Fixed and working. Thanks everyone for the help.

Hello I'm making a javascript/jQuery button that when its clicked, a Div appears (display: inline-block), and when its clicked again the Div goes back to display: none.  Ideally I would want to animate the movement, but I really just want to get it working first.

My button...

```
 <button> Menu Test </button>
```

My function (updated)...

```
<script>

$("button").click(function(){
    $("#flexMenu").toggle("slow", function() {

});
});

</script>
```

The CSS for flexMenu...

```
 #flexMenu {
 /* display: inline-block;*/
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  margin: 3.9em 0 0 0;
  padding: .25em;
  width: 15%;
  height: 6em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  z-index: 100;
 }
```

I'm really just to sure how to grab the display property of the ID and change it.  I've done a hover function before using CSS ease-out to make divs grow in size when hovered and change class by using $(this).toggleClass(nameOfClass), but I have never tried just changing an element.  The other questions like this didn't really fit just changing the display value. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use jquery :

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#flexMenu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Ah yes thats how I have it set up.  How will toggle know to target the display style?

Comment: @user3622460 if you read the documentation of `.toggle()`, it handles the display style for you http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @user3622460 the .toggle() methode does all the work for you, just give your button an id for example 

<button id="btn"> Menu Test</button>
and the js will be 

$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#flexMenu").toggle();
});

Answer (score 1):

Updated with the jQuery `.on()` method which allows you to bind specific events to that button (event listeners).

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
    $('#flexMenu').toggle("slow");
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5svyt19c/)

Comment: I updated the post with the function you suggested.  I still can't get it to work for some reason.  I posted the CSS for #flexMenu.  I also read the documentation toggle and it says it toggles the display, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything for me.

Comment: Hi, I updated the example one I fully understood what you were trying to accomplish.